# Cannot access any files Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, permissions, files

I cannot open any files on my Manjaro Linux laptop.  I really can't remember why it happened but I restarted my computer and now I dont have read/write access to any folder or file even though I've logged in.

Comment: Can you post the error which you are getting while trying to read/write a file.

Comment: I'm getting a permission denied when trying to cd to Downloads for example

Comment: Can you post the output of this command: $ ls -la /home/

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 23.02.2013 21:50 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root   4096 17.03.2013 10:43 ../
drwx------ 38 max  users  4096 15.03.2013 05:44 max/
drwx------  2 root root  16384 23.02.2013 19:18 lost+found/

Comment: sorry i dont know how to format it line by line

Comment: @abacusasian it is giving error for root user or what ?

Comment: @abacusasian Please post exact error/issue that your are getting on the screen

Comment: @buffer0verflow to learn about formatting, either read the help, or click edit on someone else's post to see the magic syntax they used. And when people ask for more info, you should append it to your original post. And to paste stuff from the shell there, just start with a blank line and four-space indent the content you paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the mode at which the partition is mounted i.e whether it is mounted in read-only or read-write mode.

You can use `mount` command to check that. If this is the issue, then you can edit the `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: what should i see if my drive is r/w?

Comment: The safe way to check that is `cat /proc/mounts`. `mount` shows just the content of /etc/mtab - not necessarily the kernel's view on reality. Those lines contain "rw" or "ro".

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you got all your files owned by root... try, as root:

```
chown -R user:group /home/user
```

where `user` is the user you log in as, `group` is the group you belong to (probably also called `user`, `grep user /etc/passwd` will give you something like:

```
user:x:1000:1000:Joe User:/home/user:/bin/bash
```

the second number is the group number).

Be *extremely* careful with what you do as root (or using `sudo`, it's the same thing), root is all-powerful and can easily destroy your system.

Comment: If you want to chown to the primary group then you can simply use `chown -R user: ...` instead. And playing the smart ass: root can easily destroy most systems but since the invention of LSMs and file caps it's not all-powerful any more... ;-)